# Mathematics Graduate Student Summer Opportunities

Tags: education

I am currently a mathematics graduate student at Western Kentucky University in Bowling Green, KY. I am looking for some kind of summer opportunity to participate in during summer 2011.

Does anyone have any suggestions of good opportunities or a good list of opportunities?

I would really appreciate it!

I am more interested in pure mathematics than I am in applied mathematics. My favorite areas are set theory, complex variables/analysis, topology, difference equations, difference(discrete) calculus, and time scale calculus.

I am really looking to broaden my horizons though with new and interesting topics.

Naturally, I am going to speak with my advisor and professors, but I would like to get insight from others as well.

Comment: To avoid repeat answers, I am linking this question posted on math overflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46561/mathematics-graduate-student-summer-opportunities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert Krasny from University of Michigan, has an excellent resource page

http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~krasny/fellowships_etc.html

There is also a good list here

http://www.phds.org/graduate-school/preparing/summer-internships-2/

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!